# SQL Developer error: Windows cant' find the target

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

During the SQL Developer startup I recevie an error: `Windows cant' find the target.`
The error window pops-up around 30 times. After I close the window 30th time SQL Developer works normally.

Things is tried to do:

- delete folder with SQL Developer settings: `%AppData%\Roaming\SQL Developer`
- install new version of SQL Developer

Nothing helps.

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]